# generate sample from pre specified correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to generate samples from a large dataframe, but with the requirements of keeping a fixed proportion of some pre-specified columns.
Here is a simplified example to work with:

```
set.seed(1234)
respondent <- 1:1000
red <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
blue <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
green <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
black <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
grey <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)

my.new.df <- data.frame(respondent, red ,blue,green,black,grey)
lapply(my.new.df[,2:6],sum)
$red
[1] 518

$blue
[1] 485

$green
[1] 515

$black
[1] 481

$grey
[1] 508
```

Now, say for example I wanted to take a sample of 100 from this my.new.df keeping the correlation structure of the data:

```
cor(my.new.df[,2:6])
              red         blue       green       black         grey
red   1.000000000  0.047131752  0.01293420  0.02740555  0.007429767
blue  0.047131752  1.000000000 -0.03913522 -0.02516950  0.006483748
green 0.012934202 -0.039135222  1.00000000 -0.02288682 -0.066518451
black 0.027405546 -0.025169500 -0.02288682  1.00000000 -0.017406799
grey  0.007429767  0.006483748 -0.06651845 -0.01740680  1.000000000
```

Comment: What's wrong with a random sample? How "exact" do those proportions need to be because with 100 you can't match them exactly? In your simulation all your variables are independent, but in real data you may have correlations that will make things more difficult to get each proportional subsets. What exactly do you how to accomplish with this subset?

Comment: For starters, it does not need to be exactly the same but in the ball park, in my real example the proportions are more diverse, a range from 10% to 50%. However, if you have any ideas of how to generate sample from data where the variables are not independent, that would be ideal! I have correlation between the data in the real data set.

Comment: Again, you haven't said what you plan to do with this data, but bootstrapping is a common statistical technique where you take multiple random subsets, calculate your statistic over them, then average those statistics to make inferences about the population.

Comment: I have one other column containing ratings, and my thinking was to try to generate many samples and calculate some statistics and then vary one of the proportions in the strata while keeping the others constant and evaluate how stable the sampling statistic is (for the rating column)...when thinking on it again I definitely need the covariance structure..